# Why am I getting the previous value of state?

Tags: reactjs, express, react-hooks, react-state

I am trying to make a service call inside the eventhandler called onChange of the value in select. But inside my event handler, either I am getting the previous value of state or my state is not getting updated.

What could be causing this?

How can I handle this change of state so it gives me the updated value?

This is my Component

```
function CountryDataAra65(props){

const [countryOption, setCountry] = useState("Select a country");
const [countryData, setCountryData] = useState([]);

var cardBody;

// Tags for table
const PPTag = "Purchasing Power";
const CLTag = "Cost of Living";
const HCTag = "Health Care";
const CRTag = "Crime Index";
const PLTag = "Pollution Index";
const QLTag = "Qualit of Life";

// When a country is selected
// When this event handler is called onChange of select, the state(countryOption) gives me the previous value
async function onCountrySelected(e){
    const val = e.target.value;
    await setCountry(val);

    console.log(countryOption);
    
    // To pass country as object
    const country = {
        "country": countryOption
    }

    // To get country's data
    // This is a service call
    await getCountryData(country)
    .then(data =>{
        setCountryData(data);
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error =>{
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

Below is my select input

```
<select className="form-control" aria-label="Default select example"  onChange={onCountrySelected}>
  <option selected>Select a country</option>
  {
    props.data.map((item, key) => {
      return (
        <option defaultValue={item} key={key}>{item}</option>
      )        
    })
  }
</select>
```

Comment: Can you please specify where exactly are you getting the old value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React hooks (out of the box) are not async. So calling `await setCountry` doesn't do anything. Secondly, if you want the updated value of `countryOption` inside the `onCountrySelected` method, you can simply use the value from `e.target.value`.

```js
function CountryDataAra65(props) {
  const [countryOption, setCountry] = useState("Select a country");
  const [countryData, setCountryData] = useState([]);

  var cardBody;

  // Tags for table
  const PPTag = "Purchasing Power";
  const CLTag = "Cost of Living";
  const HCTag = "Health Care";
  const CRTag = "Crime Index";
  const PLTag = "Pollution Index";
  const QLTag = "Qualit of Life";

  // When a country is selected
  // When this event handler is called onChange of select, the state(countryOption) gives me the previous value
  async function onCountrySelected(e) {
    const val = e.target.value;
    setCountry(val);

    console.log(countryOption);

    // To pass country as object
    const country = {
      country: val,
    };

    // To get country's data
    // This is a service call
    await getCountryData(country)
      .then((data) => {
        setCountryData(data);
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dharman I did that and it works, it solves my problem but why isnt the state getting updated right away

Comment: [this](https://linguinecode.com/post/why-react-setstate-usestate-does-not-update-immediately) article does a great job of explaining the exact reason as to why setState is not immediate.

Comment: The thing is after updating the countryOption state. I also tried executing another method using countryOption state in it and it also gave me the previous value of state. Why so?